# Spliting strings into groups of similar strings

Tags: algorithms, strings, clustering

I would like to group a list of strings into groups of strings differing by max 1 character:

For instance, given:

```
[John, Alibaba, Johny, Alidaba, Mary]
```

I would expect three groups:

```
[John, Johny],
[Alibaba, Alidaba],
[Mary]
```

My first thought was about using some clustering algorithm with Levenshtein distance but that seems like an overkill to me.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to specify the task more clearly?  For instance, it's not clear what outputs are valid if the input is something like [aaaa, abaa, aaba].

Comment: Are you looking for a selection that minimizes the number of output lists or is your goal to maximize some target function (the number of strings in the shortest output list..)?